# Properly using QMAKE_POST_LINK in Qt project file

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, qmake

When adding commands to QMAKE_POST_LINK using += operator should I need to add a semicolon?

For example,

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += mv somefile1.dat /some_location1; # semicolon
QMAKE_POST_LINK += mv somefile2.dat /some_location2
...
```

Without the semicolon Qt doesn't separate the commands.

Is this proper functionality?

Comment: `+=` is simply an operator to append a string to a variable, qmake interpret this variable after all operators are executed, therefore without `;` you'll just have a malformed command-line. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-language.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `$$escape_expand(\n\t)` at the end of the each command.

Some examples (just took from my real app):

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += "cp -f $$OUT_PWD/$$DESTDIR/crashreporter.app/Contents/MacOS/crashreporter $$MACX_APP_MACOS_DIR" $$escape_expand(\n\t)
QMAKE_POST_LINK += "cp -R" $$VMSCLSHARED_DYLIBS $$MACX_APP_FW_DIR/ $$escape_expand(\n\t)
```

Here is one yet example: https://gist.github.com/Wohlstand/3d9455c4baddc057de60e511f7280b87